# Plot average of an array in python

Tags: python, numpy, average

I have a 2D array of temperature over time data. There are about 7500 x-values and as much corresponding y-values (so one y for every x).

It looks like this:
[image: plot]

The blue line in the middle is the result of my unsuccessful attempt to draw a plot line, which would represent the average of my data. Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=np.genfromtxt("data.csv")
temp_av=[np.mean(data[1])]*len(data[0])
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(111)
plt.scatter(data[0],data[1])
plt.plot(data[0],temp_av)
plt.show()
```

However what I need is a curve, which will follow the rise in the temperature. Basically a line which will be somewhere in the middle of data points.

I googled for some solutions, but all I found were suggestions how to compute an average in cases where you have multiple y-values for one x. I understand how to do that, but it doesn't help in this case.

My next idea would be to use a loop to compute an average for every 2 neighbor points. But I am not sure how to do that best and if there aren't better solutions.

Also, I understand that what I need is to compute an other array. Plotting is only for representation.

Comment: Your idea to use a loop to make a loop to compute an average is correct - but you should do it for each x value, not every 2 neighbor points, at least if I understand correctly what it is you want.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517722/weighted-moving-average-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add trendline in python matplotlib dot (scatter) graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447191/how-to-add-trendline-in-python-matplotlib-dot-scatter-graphs)

Answer (score 1):

If I undestrand correclty, what you are trying to plot is a trend line. You could do it by using the numpy function 'polyfit'. If that's what you are looking for, try this small modification to your code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=np.genfromtxt("data.csv")
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(111)
plt.scatter(data[0],data[1])

pfit = np.polyfit(data[0], data[1], 1)
trend_line_model = np.poly1d(pfit)

plt.plot(data[0], trend_line_model(data[0]), "m--") 
plt.show()
```

This will plot the trend line in dashed magenta